# How to use Swagger For Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, swagger, endpoint

I have a web service on Laravel 5.,4 but I need a documentation about it. I was looking options, and it seems like Swagger is one of the best options for this (if you have any other recommendation please let me know). However, I can see a lot of versions of it, I was looking into the official page but I don´t sure what I need to implement.

I will appreciate if you can give some suggestions or examples about it.

Comment: Install this package https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger and then follow this link https://medium.com/@mahbubkabir/discovering-swagger-in-laravel-rest-apis-cb0271c8f2 to generate simple API. Am developing on the same. Will let you know the in details once I finish up with my current job.

Comment: Please check this article which might be helpful to you. https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/how-to-use-darkaonline-l5-swagger-in-laravel/

Comment: There is another post where you can lean how to authenticate Api with token. https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/laravel-swagger-authenticate-users-via-bearer-token/

Answer (score 5):

1. Install darkaonline/l5-swagger:

   composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger:~5.0"
2. Write correct phpdoc annotations for swagger (example: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/Examples/petstore.swagger.io)
3. Then run:

   php artisan l5-swagger:publish
4. http://yourhost.dev/api/documentation will show you swagger-ui